# EOT in conditional section of bash script

Tags: bash, ftp

So, i'm trying to get an ftp script working but i'm hitting a snag. Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST='192.168.178.122'
USER='ftpuser'
PASSWD='passa.2015'
DATE=`date +%d-%m-%Y`
FILE="archive-"$DATE".tar.gz"

prep=0
echo "File is="$FILE
echo "Prepare_val="$prep
if [ $prep -eq 0 ]
    then
        find Web -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -not -type l -print0 | tar --null --files-from - -cpzvf $FILE

        ftp -n $HOST << EOT
        user $USER $PASSWD
        put $FILE
        quit
        bye
        EOT
fi
```

When i try and run this script, it returns the following error:

```
ftp-script.sh: 22: ftp-script.sh: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "fi")
```

If i remove the EOT section, it executes fine, but the EOT is the only means by which the ftp commands can be run without needing user intervention. Does anyone know how to place an EOT in a conditional without causing the error I get.

Comment: try using <<-EOF instead of <<EOF (Note the hyphen) to persist your indentation

Comment: Also, `<<-EOF` requires tabs alone as indentation, not spaces.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can persist your indentation to have better readability like this:

contents of script.bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
#normal usage
cat <<EOF
abcd
xyz
EOF
echo "*************************"
#using heredoc without script indentation
if [[ true ]]; then
    cat <<EOF
abcd
xyz
EOF
fi
echo "*************************"
#using heredoc with script indentation
if [[ true ]]; then
    cat <<-EOF
    abcd
    xyz
    EOF
fi
```

Output:

```
$ ./script.bash 
abcd
xyz
*************************
abcd
xyz
*************************
abcd
xyz
$
```

**Bottom line: use `<<-EOT` instead of `<<EOT` (Note the hyphen) to persist your indentation**

Comment: The heredoc delimiter can only be indented with tabs, not spaces, with `<<-EOF`.

Answer (score 7):

The closing `EOT` must be at the beginning of the line, with no previous spaces or tabs.
Try this:

```
        ftp -n $HOST << EOT
        user $USER $PASSWD
        put $FILE
        quit
        bye
EOT
```